# Rails 3.2 has-and-belongs-to-many update association unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

In my 'notification' model I have a method (notification and contact models both has and belongs to many):

```
`def self.update_contact_association(contact, notification)
     unless contact == nil
         notification.contacts.clear
         c = Contact.find(contact)
         notification.contacts << c
     end
 end`
```

that updates the association between a specific notification and contact.  It takes a notification object(row) and a list of contact ids.  The method works fine, given a single contact id 1 and a notification with the id of 4 updates the table should and will look like this:

```
notification_id    contact_id

4                  1
```

The problem comes in when trying to write a unit test to properly test this method.  So far I have:

```
'test 'update_contact_association' do
     notification = Notification.find(4)
     contact = Contact.find(1)
     Notification.update_contact_association([contact.id], notification)
'end
```

Running the test method causes no errors, but the test database is not updated to look like the above example, it is just blank.  I'm pretty sure I need to use a save or update method to mimic what the controller is doing, but I'm not sure how.  I just need the unit test to properly update the table so I can go ahead and write my assertions.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated for I need to test several methods that are very similar/the same as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Tests will generally run any database queries inside of a transaction and rollback that transaction when finished with each test. This will result in an empty database when the tests complete.

This is to ensure a pristine starting point for each test and that tests are not interdependent. A unit test is supposed to be run in isolation, so it should always start from the same database/environment state. It also runs on the smallest amount of code possible, so you don't have to worry about code interaction (yet!).

When you're ready to worry about code interacting, you'll be wanting to build out integration tests. They're longer and will touch on multiple areas of code, running through each different possible combination of inputs so touch as many lines of code as possible (this is what code coverage is all about).

So, the fact that it's blank is normal. You'll want to assert some conditions after you run your `update_contact_association` method. That will show you that the database is in the expected state and the results of that method are what you expect to happen.

Comment: Thank you for you help!  As I understand it the database is cleared and then loaded when you run 'rake test:units.'  So after running my tests I can still see the sample data that is manipulated by other tests.  The association, however, isn't being changed and stored.